# XText development in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xtext

XText development forces to develop the grammar in an Eclipse instance and then starting a new Eclipse workbench with your developed plug-ins installed (Run As -> Eclipse application). Since I always have memory issues and the grammar is stable I would like to start only one instance (the one with my plug-in) directly.

However I am not able to build the correct and necessary arguments for the JVM.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried to read the command line start parameters from jConsole. I took the

- JVM parameters
- Class path
- connection name

and came to this parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\javaw.exe"  -Xms40m -Xmx384m
-Declipse.pde.launch=true -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -jar C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-name Eclipse -showsplash 600 -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data C:\Work\Projekte\DSL/../runtime-EclipseApplication
-configuration file:C:/Work/Projekte/DSL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/
-dev file:C:/Work/Projekte/DSL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties
-os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -nl de_AT -consoleLog
```

However, the model view is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider exporting the new features or plug-ins directly to the IDE. E.g. when you export a features, you have the option to "Install into host. Repository" as shown below.

[image: Deployable Feature Export Wizard]

Comment: In my case the solution doesn't work because I get errors during the export, but it should definitively work that way. Thank you for your answer! Strange is that it works when starting it directly instead of exporting.

Comment: Another solution is to 1) use the option "Directory:" for the export 2) copy manually the jar into <eclipse-dir>/plugins

Comment: @Aubin I wouldn't do that! It will make it impossible to manage the Eclipse installation afterwards. If you go for this solution, install from the directory rather than copying directly!